# Problems in attaching a PaymentMethod to a Customer using Stripe API and cfhttp

Tags: stripe-payments, cfhttp, cfhttpparam

Following the Stripe documentation, which uses curl, I have tried the code:

```
<cfhttp   method = "POST"  url="https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_methods/pm_1LCuutGKxC2502V8WNrkE3Ja"   result = "result">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer sk_test_51...."> 
    <cfhttpparam type="FormField" name="customer" value = "cust_admin_1">
.....
</cfhttp>
```

where pm_1LCuutGKxC2502V8WNrkE3Ja is the Payment Method id from the JSON response when the card payment method was set up.

The above code gives the error:
**You cannot attach a PaymentMethod to a Customer during PaymentMethod creation. Please instead create the PaymentMethod and then attach it using the attachment method of the PaymentMethods API.**

Of course the PaymentMethod had already been created, and indeed if I change the ID slightly I get the message
**No such PaymentMethod: pm_1LCuutGKxC2502V8WNrkE3Ja22**
as would be expected.

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Answer (score 0):

The `customer` parameter isn't available when [updating an existing Payment Method](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/update) object. If you're looking to attach a Payment Method to a Customer, you should instead use [this endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach).

Please note that the attach endpoint **cannot** facilitate 3DS authentication flows in the likely event that the bank/issuer requests authentication. It is therefore **not** recommended you create and attach Payment Methods this way, but instead use [Setup Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse).